# How do I create a custom directive in Angular.js for a uikit component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to integrate [angular.js](https://angularjs.org/) with [uikit](http://getuikit.com/). I know I am sort of on the right track as I get the modal to pop up, but unfortunately only when clicking the page link in the nav!? Can someone explain why that's happening?

my directive:

```
app.directive('animationOverlay', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    };


    function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        var modal = $.UIkit.modal(".modalFunc");

        if (modal.isActive()) {
            modal.hide();
        } else {
            modal.show();
        }

    }
});
```

my html:

```
<div animation-overlay id="modal-1" class="uk-modal modalFunc">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-dialog-lightbox">
      <a href="" class="uk-modal-close uk-close uk-close-alt"></a>
        <img width="600" height="400" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4NCjwhLS0gR2VuZXJhdG9yOiBBZG9iZSBJbGx1c3RyYXRvciAxNi4wLjQsIFNWRyBFeHBvcnQgUGx1Zy1JbiAuIFNWRyBWZXJzaW9uOiA2LjAwIEJ1aWxkIDApICAtLT4NCjwhRE9DVFlQRSBzdmcgUFVCTElDICItLy9XM0MvL0RURCBTVkcgMS4xLy9FTiIgImh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnL0dyYXBoaWNzL1NWRy8xLjEvRFREL3N2ZzExLmR0ZCI+DQo8c3ZnIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgaWQ9IkViZW5lXzEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4Ig0KCSB3aWR0aD0iNjAwcHgiIGhlaWdodD0iNDAwcHgiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA2MDAgNDAwIiBlbmFibGUtYmFja2dyb3VuZD0ibmV3IDAgMCA2MDAgNDAwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj4NCjxyZWN0IGZpbGw9IiNGNUY1RjUiIHdpZHRoPSI2MDAiIGhlaWdodD0iNDAwIi8+DQo8ZyBvcGFjaXR5PSIwLjciPg0KCTxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNEOEQ4RDgiIGQ9Ik0yMjguMTg0LDE0My41djExM2gxNDMuNjMydi0xMTNIMjI4LjE4NHogTTM2MC4yNDQsMjQ0LjI0N0gyNDAuNDM3di04OC40OTRoMTE5LjgwOEwzNjAuMjQ0LDI0NC4yNDcNCgkJTDM2MC4yNDQsMjQ0LjI0N3oiLz4NCgk8cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjRDhEOEQ4IiBwb2ludHM9IjI0Ni44ODEsMjM0LjcxNyAyNzEuNTcyLDIwOC43NjQgMjgwLjgyNCwyMTIuNzY4IDMxMC4wMTYsMTgxLjY4OCAzMjEuNTA1LDE5NS40MzQgDQoJCTMyNi42ODksMTkyLjMwMyAzNTQuNzQ2LDIzNC43MTcgCSIvPg0KCTxjaXJjbGUgZmlsbD0iI0Q4RDhEOCIgY3g9IjI3NS40MDUiIGN5PSIxNzguMjU3IiByPSIxMC43ODciLz4NCjwvZz4NCjwvc3ZnPg0K" alt="">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also can anyone confirm if you don't use directives, the result will cause the methods in `uikit` not to function?

Comment: Not sure I can add other pieces to contribute. Any suggestions?